# How to call the API with dynamic url parameters based on number of id's using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, angular8

I have the API from the backend and I need to call the API with id's changing dynamically.
ex API:
http://13.567.544/api/meters/start?id=m1  (for id 'm1')
**and for m2**
http://13.567.544/api/meters/start?id=m2 (for id 'm2') and so on.

How to call the above  API with id's(m1,m2,m4,....) passing dynamically(pass ids dynamically in API),and I want the typescript and service code for the same.  Also I want to check with the console if it is working or not in developer tools.

In
Postman, I received the following.

```
{
    "status": true,
    "action": "m1 meter started"
}
```

and for 'm4'

```
{
    "status": true,
    "action": "m4 meter started"
}
```

the 'm' values will be changed according to the server.

**.service.ts**

```
meterstart( token) {
  let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
    }),
    Params:new URLSearchParams({
   'id':this.meters.name;
       })
  
  };
  this.http.get(environment.apiUrl+'/api/meters/start'+this.id,httpOptions).subscribe(
  (data:any)=>{
  console.log(data);

                }
```

**.component.ts**

```
jammerstop(){
  this.data=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data"));
  
 console.log(data);
}
```

**I want the *hard code* for  the above component and service code for calling the API, because I have not involved in this scenario**